# Is This Pin-Out for S-Video or Composite Video?

Tags: video, analog

I have never seen a pin out utilizing video- and video+ before. My first assumption would be that it's for analog video transmission, probably composite video.

### Pin Function

1. Video-
2. Video+
3. 74 VDC
4. AUX+
5. Ground
6. AUX-
7. RS-485 -/A
8. RS-485 +/B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recognize this connector, but I can say that your assumption is incorrect. Video+/- isn't "two cables", it's just a way of notating the two wires (like say, signal and ground) needed for a complete circuit. The same is true for the AUX and RS485 circuits.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That answers what I need to know.